# How to defined correct data type for object

Tags: reactjs, types, typeerror, typescript-typings, prop

I'm passing this as my props

```
 export const LineChart = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      date: "2021/07/01",
      books: 10
    },
    {
      date: "2021/07/02",
      books: 25
    },
    {
      date: "2021/07/03",
      books: 15
    },
    {
      date: "2021/07/04",
      books: 48
    },
    {
      date: "2021/07/05",
      books: 102
    },
    {
      date: "2021/07/06",
      books: 59
    },
    {
      date: "2021/07/07",
      books: 37
    }
  ];
  return <Chart data={data} />;
};
```

And I'm receiving those data in my components as props

```
export const Chart = ({ data }:**type of data***) => (
    <chart
      data={data}
      type="monotone"
      dataKey="reviews"
      stroke="#c80acc"
      activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
    />  );
```

How we define the type of prop **Data** in typescript, I'm new to typescript, I'm receiving data as an object. datatype any works, but it's not proper type, How to define the data type of above object & get rid of type error,(code is working fine)

Comment: Does the manual give that answer?  (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare like this:

```
{ data }: {data: Array<{ date: string; books: number }>}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach,

```
     export const Chart = ({ data }: {data: { date: string; books: number }[]}) => (
             <chart data={data}
               type="monotone"
              dataKey="reviews"
              stroke="#c80acc"
             activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
        /> );
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-moon-hr9ne?file=/src/App.tsx